# Cosa significa "niente di che" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> -- Non si deve preoccupare, signora. Fil mi sembrava a posto, sereno. Stava bene, ecco. Addirittura m'è sembrato un po' ingrassato... 
>   -- Ma cosa vi siete detti, Cami? 
>   -- Niente. L'ho salutato da lontano. Ma lui non mi ha neanche vista. Ero andata cosí, avavo letto che lui c'era, mi sembrava carino fare un salto, ma *niente di che*. 
>   -- Ma come *niente di che*? Adesso non potresti chiedergli per favore che cosa... 
>   -- Ma signora, io adesso sono in Francia! 
>   -- Ah, non sei piú lí... 
>   -- No...

Si tratta del colloquio telefonico tra una madre e Cami,  l'ex fidanzata di suo figlio Fil. Questa donna ha saputo che Cami ha trovato Fil a Oxford e le telefona per averne notizie, perché lei, la madre, non riesce più a comunicare con suo figlio.

Nel [dizionario De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/niente) ho trovato questa definizione della locuzione "niente di che":

> **niente di che**
>   loc.avv. 
>   loc.agg.inv. **CO** che è di scarso valore o di qualità bassa: un libro niente di che

Comunque, non riesco a capire il significato di questa espressione nel brano precedente. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 1):

La mia interpretazione di quel *niente di che* è *niente di più*, *niente di particolare*. Cioè che lei è andata lì perché sapeva che lui era lì, ma voleva giusto fare un salto lì e niente di più di quello. Cioè non voleva intrattenersi a lungo né farsi notare più di tanto, nella speranza che lui la notasse ma non capisse che era andata lì apposta per lui.

In altre parole secondo me il *niente di che* non si riferisce alla ragione per cui Cami ha voluto fare un salto lì, ragione che invece mi sembra molto forte e con grandi aspettative, bensì si riferisce al tipo di visita che aveva intenzione di fare, cioè giusto un'apparizione estemporanea invece di una presenza più marcatamente "premeditata", ad es. concordata in anticipo con lui o con altri, protratta nel tempo, ecc.

Secondo me quando la madre chiede con stupore *Ma come niente di che?* intende qualcosa di questo tipo: *Cosa ?? Se sapevi che lui era lì, perché hai pensato di fare solamente un salto ? Saresti dovuta andare lì con decisione e con la chiara intenzione di incontrarlo e parlargli.*

Comment: Ho riportato un brano più ampio. Magari così si possa capire meglio.

Comment: @Charo Sì, secondo me il _niente di che_ non si riferisce alla ragione per cui ha voluto fare un salto lì, che invece mi sembra molto forte e con grandi aspettative, bensì si riferisce al tipo di visita che aveva intenzione di fare, cioè giusto un'apparizione estemporanea invece di una presenza più marcatamente "premeditata", ad es. concordata in anticipo con lui o con altri, protratta nel tempo, ecc. Secondo me quando la madre chiede con stupore _Ma come niente di che?_ intende: Cosa ?? Se sapevi che lui era lì, perché volevi solo fare un salto invece di andare lì ad incontrarlo e parlargli ?

Comment: Potresti aggiornare la tua risposta scrivendo tutto questo?

Comment: @Charo Ah, giusto :D  Fatto.

Answer (score 0):

Sì, nel contesto riportato significa che questa che dice 'niente di che' ha fatto un salto lì senza una ragione particolarmente importante o, comunque, senza che fosse certa di ottenere un apprezzabile risultato, come se avesse voluto fare un mero tentativo di suscitare qualcosa in qualcuno, a prescindere dall'apprezzamento dell'esito.

Ciononostante, sottolinerei che, spesso, quando un italiano -- e soprattutto un'italiana -- dice 'niente di che' c'è da aspettarsi che tenda a celare un concreto senso d'aspettativa non corrisposta; è difficile capire dallo stralcio se questo è il caso della citata tipa della Mastrocola, comunque.

Comment: @Charo, ti è piaciuta la risposta?